# How use a interface?

Tags: php, interface

I want to use an interface from an API in my project this:

```
<?php
namespace Spatie\Dropbox;
interface TokenProvider
{
    public function getToken(): string;
}
?>
```

How can I implements this in my code? its like:

```
class refresh implements Spatie\Dropbox\TokenProvider{
    public function getToken(){
          $this->getToken();
    }
}
```

keep give me the error:"**Declaration of refresh::getToken() must be compatible with Spatie\Dropbox\TokenProvider::getToken(): string in**"

If anyone can explain why this is and how it works correctly I would be very grateful.

Comment: Interface is `getToken(): string`, you have `getToken()`. But an interface is not ready-to-use code, it's just a specification on how to write your own code and you're seemingly trying to invoke some existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the method should return string, and you are re-calling it again and again, this should be like this:

```php
class Refresh implements Spatie\Dropbox\TokenProvider
{
    // as you see here `:string`, it means the method should return a string
    public function getToken(): string
    {
          return 'YOUR_TOKEN'; // it's prefered to be in a config file
    }
}
```